# Run ant unittests and read report using Jenkins shared library on the given relative path

Tags: jenkins, junit, ant, jenkins-pipeline, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to make a scripted Jenkin shared library that runs **ant unittests** command on a particular folder.

Currently, on my local, I run this command on cmd on a particular folder. After it is executed, it generates a HTML file with the JUnit report.

How can I achieve the same above goal in a scripted groovy Jenkin shared library, given that I have to use the relative path of the folder.

The sample code for the same will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure if i understood your question correct but at least it will give you some pointers into some directions.

```
dir(<path>) { //changes the current working directory, this means, this could be actually an path within your workspace
    sh script: "ant unittests" // be aware that ant needs to be available
    junit testResults: ['<path to report>'] // change this wildcard path to your needs eg. hybris/log/junit/**/*.xml
}
```

Although i am not sure in a hybris context way, where you store the reports, eg. we do have a structure of

- junit

  - unittest #xml report for unittest
  - integrationtest #xml report for integration tests

and we are using
`hybris/log/junit/**/*.xml` for all our tests results, and `hybris/log/junit/unittests/*.xml` for just the unittest results in the shared library.

To achieve this we overwrite the `junit.results.directory` for each of the executions.